# How can I write a function to get the third element from several lists?

Tags: r

for example:

```
list_data1 <- list("Red", "White",   c(1,2,3), TRUE, 22.4)
list_data2 <- list("Blue", "Yellow", c(4,5,6), FALSE, 23.6)
list_data3 <- list("Green", "Black", c(7,8,9), TRUE, 21.1)
```

I want the code below in a function:

```
data_1 <-list_data1[[3]]
data_2 <-list_data2[[3]]
data_3 <-list_data3[[3]]
```

I've already tried

```
for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]'))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), get(paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]')))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), getAnywhere(paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]')))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), objects(pattern = 'list_data')[i])
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), write(paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]')))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), writeLines(paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]')))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), eval(parse(paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]')))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), sprintf('list_data',i,'[[3]]'))
}

for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('data_',i), noquote(paste0('list_data',i,'[[3]]')))
}
```

none of them worked. How can I **write a function to assign to a new object** the third element from lists?

Answer (score 2):

It would require `get` to extract the object from the string created, then extract the `list` element and `assign` it to new object

```
for(i in 1:3) assign(paste0('data_', i), get(paste0('list_data', i))[[3]])
```

-checking

```
data_1
#[1] 1 2 3
data_2
#[1] 4 5 6
data_3
#[1] 7 8 9
```

---

Another option is `list2env`

```
 tmp <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^list_data\\d+$')), `[[`, 3)
 names(tmp <- paste0('data_', seq_along(tmp))
 list2env(tmp, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your lists in a list and use `lapply` or `sapply` to extract the specific list elements.  `lapply` would produce a list of vectors.  `sapply` would produce a matrix of vectors.  You could attach names to the output list elements or the matrix headers.

```
biglist <- list(list_data1, list_data2, list_data3)
namesx <- mapply(function(x) paste0("data_", x), 1:3)

extracts1 <- lapply(1:3, function(x) biglist[[x]][[3]])
names(extracts1) <- namesx

extracts2 <- sapply(1:3, function(x) biglist[[x]][[3]])
colnames(extracts2) <- namesx
```

It's usually better to keep related objects within a parent object (list, matrix, dataframe).  Is there a reason why the extracted vectors must exist independently in the global environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist <- function(x,y,z,...){
    x_1 <-x[[3]]
    x_2 <-y[[3]]
    x_3 <-z[[3]]
    
    list(x_1,x_2,x_3)
}


x_4 <- newlist(list_data1,list_data2,list_data3)
```

which returns

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option similar to [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409972/12158757)

```
list2env(
  lapply(
    setNames(
      list(list_data1, list_data2, list_data3),
      paste0("data_", 1:3)
    ),
    `[[`, 3
  ),
  envir = .GlobalEnv
)
```